# Blender Freezes while rotating in viewport (Spoiler: sadly it is not Auto Save)

Tags: 3d-view

I have very basic scenes and complexity - also my PC is not slow. Still, sometimes (not always) when I rotate in the viewport to view my scene, it fully freezes for 5-10 seconds. Than everything works again.

The top Google result is: Auto Save - which I haven't turned on.

Is there a way to debug this problem? Turn on logging in the hope that it results in some meaningful error message.